# AndroidManifest.xml file suddenly missing in Android Studio project after moving from Windows to Linux?

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, gradle, android-manifest

I am having an Android Studio project, that works perfectly fine with Windows and is stored in Mercurial repository. Importing it on Windows can be done without any issues, yet on Linux everything crashes, as modules cannot be read correctly - AndroidManifest.xml is apparently missing.

I am aware of other threads and I have searched for suitable solution, but I am afraid that so far I haven't managed to fix the problem.

It is very important to me, that the project is set up correctly and whenever new person clones the project it will work without issues (and without necessity of recreating the project from scratch) regarding the operating system.

The current build.gradle file in failing module is already pointing to the correct location of manifest file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

Yet I am still having the following error:

```
Error:/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: What does your app.iml file look like? Maybe the path issue is in there?

Answer (score 0):

Im am on a Mac so I don't know if it's the same, there should be two tags to the left of your code, just beside the name of your class, something like :
<> public class missingFile {
if u click on those tags, suddenly Android Studio will give you an option to open your xml file.

I hope it helps, goodluck